# Why does calling zip on an array with a block always return nil

Tags: ruby, arrays

So I was trying to take two arrays `a` and `b` return a third array such that the *n*<sup>th</sup> element of the third array is the sum of the *n*<sup>th</sup> elements of arrays `a` and `b`. I was looking at the `#zip` method which interleaves arrays such that if `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [4, 5, 6]`
`a.zip(b) = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]`. ruby-doc.org says *If a block is given, it is invoked for each output array...* While messing around with it, I found something interesting though. If you call zip with a block, it always seems to return nil. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
c = a.zip(b) { |x| x.reduce(:+) }
```

returns `nil`

```
c = a.zip(b).map { |x| x.reduce(:+) }
```

returns the desired result

Answer (score 7):

#### No

For better or for worse, that's just how it works. It *either* returns the result *or* yields it to the block; it doesn't do both.

By the way, in your example `a.zip(b)` is actually `[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]`.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation on [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) states that if a block is given, nil is returned.